# GetWindowLong(int hWnd, GWL_STYLE) return weird numbers in c#

Tags: c#

I used GetWindowLong window api to get current window state of a window in c#.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);


    Process[] processList = Process.GetProcesses();
    foreach (Process theprocess in processList)
    {

        long windowState = GetWindowLong(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);

        MessageBox.Show(windowState.ToString());

    }
```

I expected to get numbers on http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Styles.htm, but I get numbers like -482344960, -1803550644, and 382554704.

Do I need to convert windowState variable?? if so, to what?

Comment: Maybe you should convert those values to hex and compare them with what you expected. I'm not sure they are wrong.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: you are right. I should convert those values and compare.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is weird about those values? For example, `482344960` is equivalent to `0x1CC00000` which looks like something you might expect to see as a window style. Looking at the styles reference you linked to, that is `WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | 0xC000000`.

If you wanted to test for `WS_VISIBLE`, for example, you would do something like:

```
int result = GetWindowLong(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
bool isVisible = ((result & WS_VISIBLE) != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you probably want to use `GetWindowLongPtr` instead, and change the return value to a `long`.  This method uses a different return type of LONG_PTR, which sounds like what you are looking for.

**GetWindowLong** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633584(VS.85).aspx

```
LONG GetWindowLong(      
    HWND hWnd,
    int nIndex
);
```

**GetWindowLongPtr** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633585(VS.85).aspx

```
LONG_PTR GetWindowLongPtr(      
    HWND hWnd,
    int nIndex
);
```

According to MSDN if you are running 64-bit Windows you need to use `GetWindowLongPtr`, because `GetWindowLong` only uses a 32-bit LONG, which would give you negative values after it reached the end of the 32-bit LONG.  Plus it sounds like `GetWindowLong` has been superseded by `GetWindowLongPtr`, so it is probably the right way to go for future development.

This is the import you should use to return the value from `GetWindowLongPtr`.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern long GetWindowLongPtr(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
```

.NET uses 64-bit `long`s regardless of the platform.

Comment: This is probably not wrong, but also not necessarily required for `GWL_STYLE` as all window styles are still `LONG` i.e. 32-bits values.