# Bit masking an IntPtr

Tags: c#, bitmask, intptr

How do I use Binary-AND to check if a particular bit is set for an `IntPtr` object?

I'm calling `GetWindowLongPtr32()` API to get window style for a window. This function happens to return an IntPtr. I have defined all the flag constants in my program. Now suppose if I want to check whether a particular flag (say `WS_VISIBLE`) is set, I need to Binary-AND it with my constant, but my constant is of `int` type, so I cannot do that directly. Try to call `ToInt32()` and `ToInt64()` both result in (ArgumentOutOfRangeException) exception. What's my way out?

Comment: What is the exact exception you get from ToInt32?

Comment: Have you tried [`GetWindowLongPtr`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetWindowLongPtr.html)?

Comment: @Romoku: I read somewhere that `GetWindowLongPtr` is a macro that internally calls `GetWindowLongPtr32()` or `GetWindowLongPtr64()` depending upon the platform.

Comment: @LightStriker: ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Internal message is "Enum value was out of legal range."

Comment: Take a look at this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271220/getwindowlongint-hwnd-gwl-style-return-weird-numbers-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just convert `IntPtr` to an `int` (it has a conversion operator) and use logical bit operators to test bits.

```
const int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;
int n = (int)myIntPtr;
if((n & WS_VISIBLE) == WS_VISIBLE) 
    DoSomethingWhenVisible()`
```

Comment: okay, why the downvote?  Does exactly what the OP asks, simply and succinctly?

Comment: This apparently is working perfectly fine for me. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Won’t this explode if the application is running in a 64-bit runtime?

Comment: Yea, "operation resulted in an overflow" for certain styles.

Answer (score -1):

[How do I pinvoke to GetWindowLongPtr and SetWindowLongPtr on 32-bit platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343724/how-do-i-pinvoke-to-getwindowlongptr-and-setwindowlongptr-on-32-bit-platforms)

```
public static IntPtr GetWindowLong(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex)
{
    if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
    {
        return GetWindowLong32(hWnd, nIndex);
    }
    return GetWindowLongPtr64(hWnd, nIndex);
}


[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetWindowLong", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLong32(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);

[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="GetWindowLongPtr", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindowLongPtr64(HandleRef hWnd, int nIndex);
```

[GetWindowLong(int hWnd, GWL_STYLE) return weird numbers in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271220/getwindowlongint-hwnd-gwl-style-return-weird-numbers-in-c-sharp)

You can implicit cast `IntPtr` to `int` to get the result.

```
var result = (int)GetWindowLong(theprocess.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
bool isVisible = ((result & WS_VISIBLE) != 0);
```

Comment: WS_VISIBLE (as well as all the WS_ values--otherwise you couldn't write a 32-bit Windows application) is a 32-bit value.  It doesn't matter if you use only the bottom 32 bits of the windows long because you're just going to mask off everything in the top 32-bits anyway.